# Google Tag Manager Custom Variable return Undefined

Tags: javascript, return, google-tag-manager

I'm working with Google Tag Manager using a Custom JS Variable to store data about user's privacy consent.

I tried the function below with a variable for privacy that is set to `true` only if the user clicks on a specific button.

```js
function controlloConsenso() {
  var privacyAccettata = false;
  var checkPrivacy = document.querySelector(".ginger_btn_accept_all");
  checkPrivacy.addEventListener("click", function() {
    privacyAccettata = true;
  });
  return privacyAccettata;
}
```

The problem is that the variable result is `undefined` within the GTM Debugger.

When trying the script outside the first function (that GTM doesn't accept) the code works fine (I've tested it in Chrome Console).

```js
var privacyAccettata = false;
var checkPrivacy = document.querySelector(".ginger_btn_accept_all");
checkPrivacy.addEventListener("click", function() {
    privacyAccettata = true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Omit the name from your function and it should work. That is, change your custom JavaScript tag to:

```
// function controlloConsenso() {
function(){
  var privacyAccettata = false;
  var checkPrivacy = document.querySelector(".ginger_btn_accept_all");
  checkPrivacy.addEventListener("click", function() {
      privacyAccettata = true;
    });
  return privacyAccettata;
}
```